# Can I avoid having chrome-sandbox as SUID?

Tags: security, chrome

I've checked my system for SUID executables and `chrome-sandbox` is one. It is shipped with Google Chrome and some other apps like Signal or Discord.

Is having this executable a security risk while *chrome is not running*?

If so, can I get rid of this SUID executable somehow, but still keep the option to start Google Chrome occasionally (when Firefox does not work on a website)

Comment: The best way to do us run `chmod u-s <program>` or ug-s and see if you see any impact.
Also, as they are 3rd party, you should be able to get SECURITY Vulnerability report to find if there are any CVEs against a given program.